# Restart button in Kivy Game

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to make restart button for tic-tac-toe game but i cant change kivy `gridlayout` in `boxlayout`.
How to make this RESTART button?

I have tried with `instance.text`, but I could change only the text of the Restart Button

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 

symbols = ["x", "o"]; switch = 0


class TicApp(App):

    def choose(self, instance):
        global switch
        if switch % 2 == 0:
            instance.text = symbols[0]
            switch += 1
        else:
            instance.text = symbols[1]
            switch += 1    

    def restart(self, instance):
        """Pleasee help me to make restart button"""


    def build(self):
        global bl
        global gl
        gl = GridLayout(rows=3, cols=3)
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical", spacing=5)
    
        #grid 3x3 of tic-tac-toe
        for i in range(9):
            gl.add_widget(Button(text="", font_size=60, on_press=self.choose))

        #making vertical boxlayout to add RESTART button
        bl.add_widget(gl)
    
        bl.add_widget(Button(text="Restart",font_size=35, size_hint=(1, .2), on_press=self.restart))
        return bl

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    TicApp().run()
```

Comment: On the point of your restart button, what have you tried so far? Other than `instance.text`?

Comment: http://inclem.net/2019/06/20/kivy/widget_interactions_between_python_and_kv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want to reset the text of the `Buttons`? If so, try:

```
def restart(self, instance):
    global gl
    for w in gl.children:
        w.text = ''
```

Comment: Thanx very much, you really helped me!